# Flutter Multiple functions in a FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In a Future Builder im trying to use two methods with different types, both of them fetch data from the api,
the main problem that im having is that both of the function have different types, so im having problem on putting
the two methods because of their types. I tried using
Future.wait(Future[]) aswell but i was getting many errors, there errors where mostly on List,
im still trying to learn how Future Builders work, i worked with FutureBuilders before but didnt have to use two functions inside the FutureBuilder. So if anyone could implement their solution on my code, that would really help and maybe add some comments on why did you make the change so i learn for the future. As a bonus im getting the List is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> error aswell so if anyone could help with that too it would be very helpful. Tried looking into stack over flow answers for that but i couldnt figure it out since i was getting an error on this part
buildSwipeButton() {
return MenuPage(
sendData: fetchLoginData()// i was getting error here,
);
}

```
buildSwipeButton() {
    return MenuPage( // other class name from a different file
      sendData: fetchLoginData(),
    );
  }

  buildSwipeButton2() {
    return MenuPage( // other class name from a different file
      sendData2: fetchWorkingLocationData(),
    );
  }

  Future<LoginData>? fetchLoginData() async {
    var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/employees';

    String basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
        base64Encode(
          utf8.encode('${emailController.text}:${passwordController.text}'),
        );
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth},
    );
    print(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      return LoginData.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(response.body),
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load LoginData');
    }
  }

  Future<WorkingLocationData>? fetchWorkingLocationData() async {
    var url = 'https://dev.api.wurk.skyver.co/api/locations';

    String basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
        base64Encode(
          utf8.encode('${emailController.text}:${passwordController.text}'),
        );
    var response2 = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth},
    );
    print(response2.body);

    if (response2.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response2.statusCode);
      return WorkingLocationData.fromJson(
        jsonDecode(response2.body),
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load Working Location Data');
    }
  }

// other file where im trying to use Future Builder

late LoginData data;
  Future<LoginData>? sendData;
  Future<WorkingLocationData>? sendData2;

body: FutureBuilder<LoginData>(
          future: sendData, // trying to use sendData and sendData2
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              LoginData? data1 = snapshot.data;
              data = data1!;
              print(data.loginPhoneNumber);
              return afterLoginBody();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            }
            return Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
late LoginData data;
  Future<LoginData>? sendData;
  Future<WorkingLocationData>? sendData2;

body: FutureBuilder<LoginData>(
          Future.wait([sendData, sendData2]),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot{
             snapshot.data[0]; //sendData
             snapshot.data[1]; //sendData2
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: The argument type 'List<Future<Object>?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>, getting the error on Future.wait line and at context aswell, as you cann see sendData 2 is not the same type as sendData, could that be a problem

Comment: try to remove `AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>` from `builder`

Comment: now im only getting the error on the Future.wait(Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (Documentation)  Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.)
The argument type 'List<Future<Object>?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Future<dynamic>>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Future? _future;
Future<dynamic> sendData() async {
  final data1 = await sendData1();
  final data2 = await sendData2();
  return [data1, data2];
}

@override
  void initState() {
    _future = sendData()();
    super.initState();
  }

///

FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return SomethingWentWrong();
          }
          final data1= snapshot.data[0] as YourDataModel;
          final data2 = snapshot.data[1] as YourDataModel;
          
});
```